# Chrome extension with webpack style-loader couldn't find a style target

Tags: css, webpack, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, webpack-style-loader

A chrome extension I have been working on runs fine on firefox but whenever I try and run it on chrome, webpack `style-loader` throws this error:

`Couldn't find a style target. This probably means that the value for the 'insertInto' parameter is invalid.`

Once I remove the css imports, the extension will run but I need the css for the extension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some reason, if you specify in your manifest that your extension should run at `document_start`:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "matches": // ...
      "js": // ...
    }
  ],
```

On firefox this will run after the `<head>` has been constructed and so `style-loader` will successfully inject the styles. But, as per [Chrome's documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time), `document_start` will inject 
*"**before any other DOM is constructed or any other script is run.**"*

So I think the `style-loader` fails to inject the css into the `<head>` on chrome because at document start it hasn't been constructed yet.

TL;DR: Change `"document_start"` to `"document_idle"`:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*.nytimes.com/*"],
      "run_at": "document_idle",
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

Comment: That can cause FOUC so a better solution might be to specify `insertInto: 'html'` in style-loader options which appends the style element directly under document.documentElement.

Comment: @wOxxOm I think that's a valid answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was my issue as well. And your answer addresses it perfectly.